# How to solve this issue even when i use older versions i am getting same issue

Tags: flutter

Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on xml 3.6.1 and excel >=1.0.4 depends on xml ^4.1.0, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with excel >=1.0.4.

dependencies:
excel: ^1.0.0

Comment: Add contents of pubspec.yaml to your question

Answer (score 0):

Use `dependency_overrides` feature of `pubspec.yaml`. This way you will be able to override the dependency version for every other dependency which is using it. But remember this is somewhat of a hack, always be on a lookout for the latest versions of the conflicting dependencies.